# Tag synonym request [orientdb] -> [orient-db]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I want to request if people with enough power level could create a [orient-db](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/orient-db/synonyms) synonym for [orientdb](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/orientdb/synonyms) tag. There isn't enough people who would be able to do that and it seems like a right thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completed: [orientdb] -> [orient-db]

Comment: Sorry, I have written it in the wrong direction. Could you make it vice versa please? I think it's also a policy that dashless tags should have higher priority.